# Scroll Images horizontally in ListBox when displaying only active

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, slider

I have collection of Images and I need create something like carousel with bullets.

Currently I have 2 `ListBoxes`

```
    <ListBox Name="lb" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalItemsPanel}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CharacterCollectionView}}" 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CharacterContainerStyle}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Image, ElementName=lb1}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>

    <ListBox BorderThickness="0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Background="#66000000" Grid.Row="1" Name="lb1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CharacterCollectionView}}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="#4CFFFFFF" Width="6" Height="6" CornerRadius="3"></Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

1st ListBox for Images, 2nd - for bullets to change image. If click on Bullets, images changes correctly (Under change I mean setting image as selected, cause only selected items is visible)

But I need to add functionality to slide Images also without using that bullets (when you can slide images by touch or by sliding horizontaly). Currectly this only work when all images is visible.

How to make sliding for images when only selected item is visible?

Comment: Can you included a minimal example with html, css, and javascript that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Locke125, how is it related to html?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the tags on your question :)